# Cellular triangular matrix?!

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

What is the English term for "cellular triangular matrix " i.e. a matrix like e.g.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2& 4 & &  &  &  &  \\
2 & 3& 5 &  &  &  &  &  \\
7 & 8& 1 &  &  &  &  &  \\
&&&7&&&&\\
&&&&4&5&&\\
&&&&2&1&&\\
&&&&&&8&9\\
&&&&&&2&6
\end{bmatrix}
 $$

All the other elements are zeros.

What happens when we raise it to some power n?
I think effectively the smaller matrices along the main diagonal are raised to power n.

I need the English term so that I can look up some more information about these matrices and their properties.

Comment: I would call this "block diagonal."

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) is the link to wiki.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: If you answer a question in a comment, it goes into the list of unanswered questions. This site already has [over 300,000 unanswered questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered), so there is a good reason to answer questions in the answer box.

Answer (score 2):

These matrices are called [block diagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices).

Comment: Thanks. What happens when we raise it to some power $n$? Each of the blocks "along the main diagonal" gets raised to power $n$, right? Are there any other special properties of these matrices?